# Uploading Images in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

The images on my app are visible when it is used on my computer, but when I try to use it on another computer or my phone, the images are not shown. The images are uploaded through the app/input from the computers directory. I was wondering if there was a way to make the images either public (not sure what term to use) or how do I upload them via URL? I am using the Paperclip 4.2.1 gem.

Thanks!

Comment: are you uploading to amazon S3?

Comment: no, sorry I forgot to specify where. pinbit.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Did you know that heroku is a read-only system? Images you upload on it will be lost every time you push to heroku or when you app goes to sleep.

Comment: No I did not, but that makes sense. I'm pretty new to heroku and this is my first Rails app

Answer (score 2):

Best and a free solution to have your application hosted on heroku and using file upload is use google drive.
Use paperclip-googledrive gem it will help you to achieve this 
https://github.com/evinsou/paperclip-googledrive

Answer (score 1):

<s>A good alternative is use Dropbox to host this kind of static files

https://github.com/janko-m/paperclip-dropbox</s>

**UPDATE:** Obsolete due changes in Dropbox API. The author recomends [Shrine](https://github.com/janko-m/shrine) as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using `Amazon's S3` to host your files. You can get a free year.